# Is there a more concise way to find the top node in a tree that meets a criterion

Tags: c#, tree, traversal, tree-traversal

For a given node in a tree, I'm trying to find its highest ancestor (or the node itself), but without crossing a certain "barrier" in the tree (a specific node type) - if there is such a "barrier" node. If there is no "barrier" node, I want to return the top node in the tree.

Sounds more complicated than it is - here is some code:

```
    public Node GetHighestRelevantAncestorOrSelf(Node node)
    {
        Node topNode = node;
        bool newTopNodeFound;
        do
        {
            Node newTopNode = GetParent(topNode);

            newTopNodeFound = (newTopNode != null && !IsBarrierNode(newTopNode));

            if (newTopNodeFound)
            {
                topNode = newTopNode;
            }
        } while (newTopNodeFound);

        return topNode;
    }
```

Is there a better way to write this, i.e. without evaluating "newTopNodeFound" twice? Maybe using a for loop?

Comment: Is it possible for you to pass `rootNode` to `GetHighestRelevantAncestorOrSelf()`??

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar No, I don't know what the root node is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of it entirely.

```
public Node GetHighestRelevantAncestorOrSelf(Node node)
{
    Node topNode = null;
    while(node != null && !IsBarrierNode(node))
        node = GetParent(topNode = node);
    return topNode;
}
```

Although there is a slight difference in functionality between this and what you have. If your passed in `node` is a barrier node, then you would be returning that node, vs this would return `null`. If you wish to change that, modify the line `Node topNode = null;` to `Node topNode = node;`

Comment: I think that's probably the most concise solution and I've marked it as an answer. I still think my original code is easier to understand, so I'll keep it, but this definitely one definitely wins in terms of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion

```
public Node GetTopNode(Node node)
{
    var parent = GetParent(node);
    return (parent != null && !IsBarrierNode(parent))
        ? GetTopNode(parent)
        : node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this without modifying the original node is to make a new variable that references it, and then "increment" this variable in a `while(true)` loop that sets it to the parent node if it's valid:

```
public Node GetHighestRelevantAncestorOrSelf(Node node)
{
    Node result = node;

    while (true)
    {
        Node parent = GetParent(result);
        if (parent == null || IsBarrierNode(parent)) return result; // This exits the loop
        result = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used an infinite loop with a break statement before, but I think infinite loops are not a good practice.